# Hive Hbase JOIN performance & KUDU

Tags: join, hive, hbase, apache-kudu

Reading the Cloudera documentation using Impala to join a Hive table against HBase smaller tables as stated below, then in the absence of a Big Data appliance such as OBDA and a largish HBase dimension table that is mutable:

> If you have join queries that do aggregation operations on large fact
>   tables  and join the results against small dimension tables, consider
>   using Impala for  the fact tables and HBase for the dimension tables.
>   (Because Impala does a  full scan on the HBase table in this case,
>   rather than doing single-row HBase  lookups based on the join column,
>   only use this technique where the HBase  table is small enough that
>   doing a full table scan does not cause a  performance bottleneck for
>   the query.)

Is there any way to get that single key look up in another way?

In addition I noted the following on KUDU and HDFS, presumably HIVE. Does anybody have experience here? Keen to know. I will be tryiong it myself in due course, but installing parcels on non-parcelled quickstarts is not so easy...

Mix and match storage managers within a single application (or query)

```
• SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_fact_table_on_hdfs JOIN
my_dim_table_in_kudu ON ...
```

Comment: _"Is there any way to get that single key look up in another way"_ > you mean, read the huge dataset once to extract the list of keys, then retrieve the relevant records from HBase (with multiple GETs in a loop), then read again the huge dataset to perform the lookup? That would be incredibly inefficient, don't you think?

Comment: I am not making any assumptions on what is best, but have been a VLDB ORACLE DBA with performance and tuning, which is a little different of course. In BIG DATA what is a small table? Your response leads met to the KUDU option.

Comment: HBase is basically a key/value DB, designed for random access and no transactions. Hive is a batch query engine built on top of HDFS (a distributed file system for immutable, large files) and YARN (a resource manager for distributed batch jobs). Hive also has a "connector" to run Full Scans on HBase, but there is a *SERIOUS* impedance mismatch here...

Comment: On the other hand, Phoenix attempts to bring some RDBMS features -- primitive data types, table schemas, indexing, transactions -- on top of HBase. And Kudu attempts to bring some RDBMS features -- atomic Insert-Update-Deletes -- as an alternative to HDFS+YARN, but it's a Cloudera initiative, oriented towards Impala and Spark (not Hive...!)

Comment: Note also that Kudu is still immature, has no serious authentication/authorization/auditing features yet, no serious documentation (even when you are a Cloudera paying customer).

Comment: _"in Big Data what is a small table"_ > in practice, a small table can fit in the RAM of a single YARN container, as a Java HashMap -- cf. "Map join" in http://www.openkb.info/2014/11/understanding-hive-joins-in-explain.html > note that Nested Loops are not in the picture (although the post is a bit old, and I don't know exactly what kind of new toys HortonWorks is working on for its LLAP initiative)

Comment: ...and note also that it's not uncommon to request large containers (16 MB+) for specific queries, just to be able to fit a reference table (or a single bucket of a reference table) in RAM.

Comment: Ok. I am familiar with hive and impala and hbase and am soon to be a mentor on some of this. But, I am also a data warehouse person who likes dimensions. All I want is a quick lookup of of a dimension key. I should be able to qualify the scan is my view or use Kudu for a lkp.

Comment: I dont want a full scan on hbase even though I read about this

Comment: But Impala can read Hive tables so it would join with Kudu surely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146004/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-samson-scharfrichter).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Erring on the side of caution, linking with KUDU for dimensions would be the way to go so as to avoid a scan on a large dimension in HBASE when a lkp is only required.

I am retracting the latter point, I am sure that a JOIN will not cause an HBASE scan if it is an equijoin.

That said, IMPALA with MPP allows an MPP approach w/o MR and JOINing of dimensions with fact tables. The advantage of the OBDA is less obvious now. imo.